# Java web app runs slow only on production server

Tags: mysql, redhat, tomcat, java

I have a web app I built that has 1 page that loads very slowly only on my production server (RHEL).  My local dev  (Windows) and test server (Ubuntu) are no where near as powerful but this particular pages literally loads 4x faster.  It takes about 2sec on dev/test and 8 seconds on production.

This app had been running fine for years, but I noticed this slowdown after upgrading my RHEL server from 6 to 7.  This also had me upgrade my mysql to 5.7.  I have tried to match the environment on my dev machine the best I can with Tomcat, mysql, java having the same version, but its a Windows machine.

I tried allocating more memory to the JVM by doubling it in case it was a memory issue but that had no effect at all.

`-Xms1536m -Xmx2560m`

I thought maybe memory leaks were causing slowdown over time, but even after a fresh server restart I have the same issue.

I am unsure where to go from  here to figuring out where the issue is.  I can only assume its something with Redhat but I don't know.  Any ideas?

Configuration:

- Tomcat: 7
- Java: 1.8
- Mysql: 5.7
- Server: RHEL 7

**UPDATE**

After some more fine tune debugging I was able to narrow it down to a loop that has a lot of data manipulation that is taking up about 80% of the execution time.  Now there are probably ways to optimize it but my question is why is this so much slower on my powerful production server?  The same code, same loop, same data set finishes 4x quicker on my slower Windows and Ubuntu machines.  As I mentioned above, this was not an issue when I was running RHEL 6 it was only after the RHEL 7 upgrade.

Comment: You haven't mentioned the storage.  Depending on how much IO mysql is generating that could make a really big difference.  Databases tend to be read/write intensive.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard that page does a fairly big query but even with filters for small data sets its still very slow.  As far as a specific IO numbers though I don't know,  how can I determine that?

Comment: I was actually thinking more along the lines of the actual storage.  For Windows people usually recommend CrystalDiskMark; [this Unix and Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93791/benchmark-ssd-on-linux-how-to-measure-the-same-things-as-crystaldiskmark-does-i) might help you find linux equivalents.

Comment: Have you checked the timing of the request to see where it spends its time?

Comment: Would that page be a jsp?  Put a number of debug log statements so that you can find out if it eg. is losing time waiting for a database connection.

Comment: @Sven please see update

Comment: @KatherineVillyard turns out not to be a mysql issue.  Please see update.

Comment: @RaymondHolguin Since you do not have an ANSWER after your Jun 22 post, Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com or here.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf-ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report 
Optional very helpful information, includes - 
htop & top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: @raymondholguin  I suspect your posting of the additional information requested above would enable helpful Suggestions to improve your MySQL server performance.  View my profile, Network Profile, for contact info and to request by SHOP 'Free My TOP 10 Global Variable Suggestions'.  No credit card required to Create Account for this analysis to be completed for you.

Comment: [pt-config-diff](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-config-diff.html) will identfiy differences between your server(s)

Comment: @RaymondHolguin Please look at this before / after graph from a customer   https://www.instagram.com/p/BsghiDhB6v5/  then view my profile, Network profile for contact information and get in touch via Skype or email, please to improve your server response time.